# Laserjet Experts: How many power cycles per month?

Tags: power-management, hp-laserjet, printer

I recently got a nice Laserjet 8100DN for my house.  I will probably never print more than 1% of its rated monthly duty cycle.  But it runs some fairly noisy fans 24/7 if it's left on, so  I am in the habit of turning the machine off as soon as I'm done with it.

So, for all you who have a lot of experiencing administrating workgroup LaserJets, do you think I'll end up killing it from too many on-off cycles?

Comment: That's one hell of a printer for home use! I'm guessing this was second hand, maybe bought off your company? No matter how cheap it was, the lifetime cost is likely to be huge compared to running a much smaller printer more suited to the job, ideally one which consumes far less power when running and can be put into standby mode using even less.

Comment: Well, I think the lifetime cost will be low.  I bought it because for a total of $80 for everything except paper, I have enough consumables to print 40,000 pages.  Also, the duplexing allows me to save on (relatively) expensive paper.  Finally, based on statistics for this model, I should only have to buy a maintenance kit ($150) after anywhere between 50,000 and 200,000 pages from where I am now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @duffbeer703 says, the number of power cycles is probably of little consequence.  You can enable Powersave from the Configuration menu on the printer.  This will power it down to using 150W instead of 550W.  That should also silence the fans.  If the fans continue to run, there could be a hardware issue.  However, as 150W is not insignificant, turning off when not in use would likely be a good idea.  You will just have to wait while it warms up when you want to print.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correlation between power cycles and lifespan of most office equipment.

Comment: What? Uh....no. Power cycling is stressful to just about anything that has moving parts, and even somethings that don't.

Comment: Find a reliable source that indicates that power cycles cause and issue. There are many reliable sources, including the US EPA, Microsoft and all IT manufacturers that I am aware of who either say that it is fine or have no opinion.